# Regular expression extractor issue in Jmeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Regular expression extractor issue in Jmeter for the following

I would like to extract cuen from the following code.I have taken like this

```
href="/EPSF/EPSFEmpIndex.jsp?cuen=\"(.*)\"\"
```

Please help for this

```
 href="/EPSF/EPSFEmpIndex.jsp?cuen=}>aff>(faaafa>aa^>>ffcfaaff>ffaf>f>aa>>>fa>a>fa>a>aa|<f{(>(f" onMouseOver="window.status=''; return true" onClick="window.status=''; return true" onMouseOut="window.status='';return true" title="IPSF 2014-2015" target=mainfrm>IPSF 2014-2015
```

I would like to extract from this page and pass to next screen

" [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jRzn.jpg "

Comment: Share screenshot of your jmeter plan to clarify question in more detail.

Comment: Extract the regex from the response code of previous request and passing that value to b\next request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Regular expression extractor with below regular expression,

```
cuen\=(.*)" onMouseOver
```

In regex extractor you can provide which occurance you want to extract. 
Match no. is the name of parameter and its value shoud be 1 in your case for first match.

use this as reference : [Regular Expression Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

Comment: This expression is working.But i have two anchor links like this.I need to extract the first anchor tag cuen.

Comment: Hi Nachiket Kate will you provide Jmeter materials if you don't mind.I require to analyze the Jmeter reports, performing on different applications,distributed testing e.t.c.